# How to generate unique pin number similar to pre paid phone card PIN

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm that creates a secure unique random number similar to pre-paid phone cards. I did have a look at [Generating a unique 15 digite Pin code from a 10digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201023/generating-a-unique-15-digite-pin-code-from-a-10digit-number) but it did confused me more than make things clearer. Apologies to the people who contributed their time to answer that questions, it must have been my intelligence giving up on it.

Could anyone please guide me with an algorithm or a link where I can get more information please? Thank you.

Comment: Please see the FAQ regarding including signatures in questions.

Comment: Any requirements for the number of digits in your unique number?

Comment: "Secure" against what threat?

Comment: @Eric what I mean by secure is probably more like randomness so that it is impossible for an attacker to guess next valid number as as PIN codes in phone card. We all know that phone card pin numbers are a fixed length numbers yet it is very hard/(impossible?) to predict next valid number. (Not that I tried but I assume they are like that).

Comment: @Gilles there is no hard restriction on length but not longer than 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), and think of the original 10 digits as a message, and the final 5 digits generated starting with the HMAC of the first 10 as the message authentication code for that message. Here is a chunk of the article:

A business that suffers from attackers that place fraudulent Internet orders may insist that all its customers deposit a secret key with them. Along with an order, a customer must supply the order's HMAC digest, computed using the customer's symmetric key. The business, knowing the customer's symmetric key, can then verify that the order originated from the stated customer and has not been tampered with.

Comment: So pretty much number that goes out consists of a number + some sort of secret hash that can be used to validate it. 

In case of registered users like mentioned in the article snippet, the symmetric key could be already shared hence there is no need to embed the key in the message itself but in case of phone card pin number like scenario where a customer may be just any random person, the key needs to be embedded in the number itself. So I assume the security of such number is controlled by alogorithm that is used to embed the key on the message?

Comment: The user authenticates themselves by presenting the full 15-digit number. In this system the user does not need to know and should not know how the number is generated. The system could remember the HMAC and check from this that the 5 final digits are those generated from the first 10, or just remember the 15 digit numbers it has generated. If these numbers are each linked with a particular account e.g. to say how much credit there is left it may have to do that anyway. Of course if an attacker gets hold of the HMAC key they can predict 15 digit numbers, which you don't want.